# Can we run node application in net core 3.1

Tags: c#, node.js, bash, docker, .net-core

I am having a .Net Core 3.1 console application (which is work as a azure consumer for a message queue)
When executing the Consumer, based on a flag value of message property, Its need to run separate application which is written in node.js.

I decided use separate run.sh (shell script) file to call node application and run.sh file will call through c#.

Here is the code snippet I used.

```
var command = "bash";
                var myBatchFile = @"C:\Temp\spiderease_v1\run.sh"; //Path to shell script file
                var argss = @"C:\Temp\spiderease_v1\run.sh CA--STATCAN--REG--ADMIN-DATA {url} {OUTPUT_PATH} {SPIDER_EASE_HOME} {SPIDER_TEMPLATE_HOME} {TYPE}"; //this would become "/home/ubuntu/psa/PdfGeneration/ApacheFolder/ApacheFOP/transform.sh /home/ubuntu/psa/PdfGeneration/ApacheFolder/XMLFolder/test.xml /home/ubuntu/psa/PdfGeneration/ApacheFolder/XSLTFolder/Certificate.xsl /home/ubuntu/psa/PdfGeneration/ApacheFolder/PDFFolder/test.pdf"
                var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processInfo.FileName = command;   // 'sh' for bash 
                processInfo.Arguments = argss;    // The Script name 
                processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                var process = Process.Start(processInfo);   // Start that process.
                var outPut = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
```

But This won't work as expected.

**Update**:
This code snipt didn't give any error, but I am unable to ensure that file getting executed or not. because when I run this bash file directly, it produced some files in given path. here it didn't give any output.

Can someone help me out whether do I using correct implementation for this task or do I have any alternatives?

If this is an good solution, what would be the wrong in code?
(I am willing push this into docker Linux environment as well)

Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: "But this won't work as expected." - What did you expect? What actually happened?

Comment: _"But This won't work as expected."_ - Please update your question with what you expected to happen and what actually happened - we need more information.

Comment: description updated